# Play playlist of audio on website using node to create a jukebox / radio app

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, audio-streaming, shoutcast

So I have some time on my hands and thought I would make myself a little jukebox / radio type app.

It would be fairly simple, just a collection of MP3's on the server, one is chosen at random, it plays, on completion, the next one is chosen and plays. The front of this would just be a super simple page that has a player and displays the metadata.

I don't really have any experience with server programming but I'm going to look in to Node, seems like it would be good for this. I've already written a little script in Python that chooses a song from a selection and plays it (using VLC at the moment) so it should be simple to port it to Node / js.

Just wondering if someone could point me in the right direction for how to link the "player" with the "playlist".

Looking in to it, I can only find solutions involving a client and server using shoutCast or ICEcast or similar - so the playlist streams audio to a shoutcast server, and the website is just a player looking at the shoutCast URL - that seems unnecessary for me, as the streaming and the site would be the same thing.

New to a lot of this :) but I have time at the moment so happy to get stuck in!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looking now at Web Audio API
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_Web_Audio_API

Answer (score 0):

I've built something similar and opted to do almost all the work client-side.  There are several advantages:

- Less infrastructure needed (and less to go wrong)
- You can re-use normal HTTP CDNs for serving static files
- More flexibility for client changes later (like sending different content to different clients, for A/B testing)
- Potential for offline playback

No need for SHOUTcast or Icecast.  All you need to do is publish the playlist and associated files to a web server.  Client side, you can read this playlist, randomly pick an entry, and then load it via a simple `new Audio()`.

Now, when your `audio` object fires its `ended` event, set the `src` property to the URL of the next item in the playlist.  (This detail is important or Safari will stop playing audio, as they assume the user didn't want to continue.)

Answer (score 0):

I am searching for the same. I think you are right using node.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30941197)